# python combine multiple CSV by unique column/row headers

Tags: python, csv

First of all I'm a newbie to Python.  I'm trying to combine multiple data into a single CSV.  Following is the CSV format,

**file1.csv**

```
Country of Residence,2014-04,2015-04
 NORTH AMERICA ,"5,514","6,160"
  Canada ,"2,417","2,864"
  U.S.A. ,"3,097","3,296"
 LATIN AMERICA & THE CARIBBEAN ,281,293
 WESTERN EUROPE ,"37,369","34,964"
  Austria ,893,666
  Belgium ,867,995
```

**file2.csv**

```
Country of Residence,2014-11,2015-11
LATIN AMERICA & THE  CARIBBEAN ,373,418
Argentina ,47,50
Brazil ,68,122
Chille ,24,30
Colombia ,31,25
Others ,203,191
WESTERN EUROPE-OTHERS ,1330,1367
Croatia ,77,72
Greece ,408,452
Ireland ,428,343
Finland ,149,178
Portugal ,211,261
Others ,57,61
```

In the final csv, I would like to have a unique header list as,

```
Country of Residence,2014-04,2015-04,2014-05,2015-05,..2014-11,2014-11
NORTH AMERICA ,"5,514","6,160",NaN,Nan,...
Portugal, Nan,Nan,Nan,Nan,.....,211,261
```

Also I would like have the country list to be unique, so I can fill the numbers by reading the csv list.

In the following code I get unique column headers but I don't know how to make the Country column unique and add a number based on country and month of the year..

Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
for filename in glob.iglob(os.path.join('/Documents/stats/csv','*.csv')):
with open(filename,'rb') as f:
    csvIn = csv.reader(f)
    hdr = csvIn.next()
    hdr[0] = hdr[0].replace('\xef\xbb\xbf','')

    hdrList.append((len(hdr),hdr))
 hdrList.sort()

hdrs = []
template = []


for t in hdrList:
    for f in t[1]:
        print(f)
        if 
        if not (f in hdrs):
            hdrs.append(f)
            template.append('')
```

Comment: If using an additional library is not a problem, you may use pandas. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32486757/pandas-merge-several-csvs-with-one-common-column

Answer (score 0):

This code should get you on the right track.  Note: It is written for Python 3.

```
import glob
import os
import csv

class CountryData:
    """Data for one country for one period of residence."""
    def __init__(self, val1, val2):
        # XXX: What do these values represent?
        self.val1 = val1
        self.val2 = val2

class ResidenceData:
    """Data for one period of residence."""
    def __init__(self):
        self.start_date = ""
        self.end_date = ""
        self.countries = {}

residence_data_list = []
countries = set()
for filename in glob.iglob(os.path.join('/Documents/stats/csv','*.csv')):
    residence_data = ResidenceData()
    residence_data_list.append(residence_data)
    with open(filename,'r') as f:
        csvIn = csv.reader(f)
        for hdr in csvIn:
            hdr[0] = hdr[0].replace('\xef\xbb\xbf','')
            if hdr[0] == 'Country of Residence':
                residence_data.start_date = hdr[1]
                residence_data.end_date = hdr[2]
            else:
                country, val1, val2 = hdr
                country = country.strip()
                country_data = CountryData(val1, val2)
                residence_data.countries[country] = country_data
                countries.add(country)

print("Country of Residence", end="")
for data in residence_data_list:
    print(",", end="")
    print(",".join([data.start_date, data.end_date]), end="")
print()
for country in sorted(countries):
    print(country, end="")
    for data in residence_data_list:
        print(",", end="")
        if country in data.countries:
            country_data = data.countries[country]
            print(",".join([country_data.val1, country_data.val2]), end="")
        else:
            print("NaN,NaN", end="")
    print()
```

Result:

```
Country of Residence,2014-04,2015-04,2014-11,2015-11
Argentina,NaN,NaN,47,50
Austria,893,666,NaN,NaN
Belgium,867,995,NaN,NaN
Brazil,NaN,NaN,68,122
Canada,2,417,2,864,NaN,NaN
Chille,NaN,NaN,24,30
Colombia,NaN,NaN,31,25
Croatia,NaN,NaN,77,72
Finland,NaN,NaN,149,178
Greece,NaN,NaN,408,452
Ireland,NaN,NaN,428,343
LATIN AMERICA & THE CARIBBEAN,281,293,373,418
NORTH AMERICA,5,514,6,160,NaN,NaN
Others,NaN,NaN,57,61
Portugal,NaN,NaN,211,261
U.S.A.,3,097,3,296,NaN,NaN
WESTERN EUROPE,37,369,34,964,NaN,NaN
WESTERN EUROPE-OTHERS,NaN,NaN,1330,1367
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply.. These are tourism data.. There are about 20+ csv files which I want combine for one csv. Your solution is good but it's not 100% what I'm looking for.  Still it gave some idea.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't care the underlying logic, you can use Pandas to do this:

```
import pandas as pd
file_list = [file1, file2]
dfs = []
for file in file_list:
    dfs.append(pd.read_csv(filepath_or_buffer=file, sep=',', index_col=0))
result_df = pd.concat(dfs, axis=1)
result_df.index.name = 'Country of Residence'
result_df.to_csv('result.csv')
```

Comment: Thanks.  I'll try this